# How to get an input from textbox using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

This is my app.route that I'm trying to reach:

```
@app.route('/advance_search',methods=['GET','POST'])
```

def advance_search():

```
    word=""
    word = request.form['kword']
    result=[]
    result=getListOfKeyWord(word)
    return render_template('advance_search.html',key=result)
```

This is the HTML I'm trying to reach from the home page (`advance_search`):

```
<form action="/advance_search" method="POST" class="col s12">
  <div class="row center">
    
      <a href="{{ url_for('advance_search') }}" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Advanced</a>
    
</div>
</form>
```

and this is the HTML of the `advance_search.html` I'm trying to reach:

```
<form action='/advance_search' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="row">
    
        <label for="first_name"><b>Keyword</b></label>
        <br>
        
      <input   id="kword" name='kword'type="text" class="btn" placeholder="type & hit Enter">
    
    
  </div>

  <div class="row center">

      <button type="submit" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row center">
    {{key}}
  </div>
 

  
</form>
```

When I try to click on the (Advanced) button in order to go to the `advance_search.htmln page I get this error:

```
**werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'kword'**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure if a post or get request is made, then you can access the request.from keys.

your function would be:

```
[...]
result=[]

if request.method == "POST":
     word=""
     word = request.form['kword']
     result=getListOfKeyWord(word)
     
     return render_template('advance_search.html',key=result)
return render_template('advance_search.html',key=result)
```

You can not access `request.form["kword"]` until a post request is made.